# Is ます omitted in "てしまいすみません"

Tags: set-phrases, keigo

I understand that しまう means unintended action, or the completion of an action. However, recently I came across this usage in the comment section on a website:

```
遅くなってしまいすみません。
```

While I understand this sentence perfectly, one part of it puzzles me greatly. So far, I've only seen ています, or てます where the い is omitted. Nonetheless, I've never see a case where ます is omitted. Here's how I'd parse this sentence:

```
遅い=>遅く
なる=>なって
しまう=>しまい（ます）
+すみません
```

After some homework done, I believe てしまい/しまって+すみません/ごめんなさい/etc. is a common usage. However, I still can't figure out how ます is missing here. Could it be that some other entirely different grammar is at play here? Please enlighten me. Thank you. (*Am I allowed to say thank you here?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「遅{おそ}くなってしまいすみません。」

is a perfectly grammatical and natural-sounding sentence.  Nothing is omitted.

In fact, it is ungrammatical to say:

> 「遅くなってしまい**ます**すみません。」

「しま**い**」 is the 連用形{れんようけい} ("continuative form") of the subsidiary verb 「しま**う**」.

So, why is the 連用形 used?  That is because the sentence does not end there.  It still continues on to say 「すみません」.

As you stated, there are a few ways to say "Excuse me for (verb phrase)."

1) 「Verb + Subsidiary Verb in 連用形 + すみません」

2)「Verb + Subsidiary Verb in te-form + すみません」

3) 「Verb in te-form + すみません」

There is no difference in meaning between those three, but 1) sounds the most formal, followed by 2) and 3) in that order.  The actual sentences will be:

1) 「遅くなって**しまい**すみません。」

2) 「遅くなって**しまって**すみません。」

3) 「遅くなっ**て**すみません。」